# How to execute jquery from address bar?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to execute jquery from address bar of Mozila Firefox..But Script is not executing..
My Code is:

```
javascript: alert('Working Fine');
```

working in google chrome but not in mozila firefox...

Comment: i dont know why people do down voting actualy its a valid question only

Comment: i am just testing buddy...javascript: $('input').remove();

Comment: if i success in this alert then i will go further...:!

Comment: Now tell me is there any way to execute that script in all browsers??

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Firefox [removed the ability to paste JavaScript into the address bar](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/885558). Use the developer tools instead.